# Id of this class is not showing in console

Tags: jquery

How to get the id of this class this is my code, Is This the right way or not Please Help.

```
jQuery("body").load(function() { 

 alert(123 + "body");

            jQuery(".tp-tab-image").each(function() {

                alert(456);

                var idi = jQuery(this).attr("id");

                console.log(idi);

            });
        });
```

Comment: What behavior do you observe?  It would be helpful to include a minimal html file to run the jquery on.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function` in the console with your code.  Using [jQuery( callback )](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) works as expected:

```html
<html>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() { 
            jQuery(".tp-tab-image").each(function() {
                var idi = jQuery(this).attr("id");
                console.log(idi);
            });
        });
    </script>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li class=tp-tab-image id=1>a
        <li class=tp-tab-image id=2>b
        <li class=tp-tab-image id=3>c
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```